# Estou tentando fazer Bhaskara no Python e mesmo com o if destacado a programação diz que não posso transformar um complex em float

Tags: python

```
a = float(input("A = "))
b = float(input("B = "))
c = float(input("C = "))
delta = float(b**2-4*a*c)
raiz = (delta ** 0.5)
if raiz is float or int:
    raiz = float(delta ** 0.5)
    x1 = float((-b + raiz) / (a * 2))
    x2 = float((-b - raiz) / (a * 2))
    if x1 == x2:
        print("O resultado é %f" % x1)
    else:
        resultado = (x1, x2)
        print("O resultado é ou %f ou %f" % resultado)
else:
    print("Não há raízes reais. Delta é %s" %delta)
```

Comment: A fórmula clássica evita que se chegue em um número complexo. Pergunta antes se o delta é negativo, não tenta nem calcular a raiz do negativo

Comment: Além do que o Jefferson falou, pra complementar, `if raiz is float or int` está errado, o correto pra verificar o tipo da variável seria `if isinstance(raiz, (float, int)):`

Comment: Obrigado galera, funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

bom eu consegui fazer de outra forma:

```
import math

# Recebendo dados
a = float(input('Digite o valor de a: '))
b = float(input('\nDigite o valor de b: '))
c = float(input('\nDigite o valor de c: '))

# Calculando o delta separadamente
delta = float(b**2 - (4*a*c))

# Calculando a raiz após obter o delta
if b < 0:
    raiz = delta * 1.5
else:
    raiz = math.sqrt(delta)

# Calculando o resto da equação após receber a raiz
if (raiz > 0) or (raiz == 0):
    x1 = (-b + raiz) / (2*a)
    x2 = (-b - raiz) / (2*a)
    if x1 == x2:  # Condicional para saber se o resultado será duas raizes iguais
        print('\nS = ', x1)  # se for igual mostrará apenas um número
    else:
        print('\nS = { %d , %d }' % (x1, x2))  # se for diferente significa que são duas raizes diferentes
else:
    print(f'\nO delta {delta} não tem raiz, pois é menor que 0 !')  # o caso se o delta for menor que 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz assim:

```
def bhaskara(a,b,c):
    delta = (b**2)-(4*a*c)
    print (str(delta) + "  delta")

    x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
    print (str(x1) + " valor de 'X1'")

    x2 = ((-b - math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a))
    print (str(x2) + " valor de 'X2'")

    xv = -b/(2*a)
    print (str(xv) + " valor de 'XV'")

    yv = -delta/(4*a)
    print (str(yv) + " valor de 'YV'")

    if delta > 0:
        print ("Duas raizes Reais " + str(x1) + ' e ' + str(x2))
    elif delta == 0:
        print ("Uma raiz real (encosta no X)")
    else:
        print (str(x2) + "Sem raízes (nao encosta no X)")

bhaskara(1,12,-13)

bhaskara(2,-16,-18)

bhaskara(1,-1,-6)
```